# Retain Session value in jsp page using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, session, angular-ngmodel

I'm using **Angularjs and Spring** .....

I had set the Session value for certain text fields using angularjs **sessionstorage** . When is reload the page or move backwards from other jsp page those values must retain in respective fields

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('namednewicno',$scope.user.namednewicno);
```

[This is the session value for ***namednewicno***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oTS2.png)

I need to display that value using **data-ng-model**

**This is my controller**

```
app.controller('FormSubmitController',[ '$scope', '$http','$window', function($scope, $http,$window) {

$scope.user = [];
    $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';


    $scope.submit = function() {            
        $window.localStorage.setItem('namednewicno',$scope.user.namednewicno);              
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('namednewicno',$scope.user.namednewicno);




        var formData = {
                "namednewicno" : $scope.user.namednewicno,
                "namedoldicno" : $scope.user.namedoldicno,
                "namedage" : $scope.user.namedage,
                "nameddriverexperience" : $scope.user.nameddriverexperience,
                "namedgender" : $scope.user.namedgender,
                "nameddrivername" : $scope.user.nameddrivername,
                "nameddriverrelationship" : $scope.user.nameddriverrelationship 
        };
        alert("controller");
        var response = $http.post('PostFormData', formData);
        response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.user.push(data);
            alert("success");
        });
        response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });
        $scope.user.namednewicno=$window.sessionStorage.getItem( 'namednewicno' );
        console.log($window.sessionStorage.getItem( 'namednewicno' ));

        //Empty list data after process
    //  $scope.user = [];

    };


}]);
```

Comment: what have you tried? something with `sessionStorage.getItem` maybe?

Comment: `$scope.user.namednewicno=$window.sessionStorage.getItem( 'namednewicno' );`

I have used getItem to assign to the same variable @Kaddath

Comment: I hope the `ng-model` of the targeted input box is set as `user.namednewicno`. What do you see if you print the value to console? `console.log($window.sessionStorage.getItem( 'namednewicno' );)`

Comment: I got the value that i have entered in the text field@MasterPo

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('NamedPopup',[ '$scope', '$http','$window', function($scope, $http,$window) {

$scope.user = [];       
        $scope.user.namednewicno=$window.sessionStorage.getItem( 'namednewicno' );


    $scope.submit = function() {            
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('namednewicno',$scope.user.namednewicno);



        var formData = {
                "namednewicno" : $scope.user.namednewicno
        };
        var response = $http.post('saveNamedDrivers', formData);
        response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.user.push(data);
            //alert("success");
        });
        response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });         
        //Empty list data after process
    $scope.user = [];

    };

}]);
```

The Html code must be like this to retain the session on html

```
<input ng-value="{{user.namednewicno}}" 
       ng-model="user.namednewicno" 
       required 
       class="form-control" type="number" />
```